# mysql select limit not working properly after insert

Tags: mysql, pagination, limit

I have a table with 6 rows of data with id=11,12,13,14,15,18 after I inserted row id=18 by cloning id=12. I select data from the table by a column (c1) and it happens that those 6 rows all have the same column value. I tried to use select limit to loop through all rows where c1=2;

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE c1=2 LIMIT 0,2 ;
```

->  I got  15,14

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE c1=2 LIMIT 2,2 ;
```

->  I got  13,11

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE c1=2 LIMIT 4,2 ;
```

->  I got 15, 18

How comes id=12 is missing and id=15 appears twice?
Did I miss anything?  Shall I resort the table or do something after I insert a new row ?

---

added below:

Things happen to be more complicated than just adding ORDER BY. All 6 rows have the same c1 column values. If I used "ORDER BY c1 DESC", then I got the same undesired result. However those 6 rows have different values on column c2. When I used "ORDER BY c2 DESC", I can loop through all 6 rows of data correctly. Now comes another question - why mysql does not ORDER and return SELECT **** ORDER by yy DESC LIMIT 2, 2 correctly when all rows have identical yy column value.

Of course we know ID will be different for all rows, but we don't know where all rows in the table would have different c1 value (which was used in ORDER BY) or not. What shall we do if we do need ORDER BY C1  ?

Comment: You need to `ORDER BY` something, otherwise limit makes no sense.

Comment: These are your data 11,12,13,14,15,18 . What you need here ?

Comment: you could read some basic SQL tutorial; this would take less time than waiting for an answer on SO. The best thing is - if you read a tutorial and try a couple of things, your questions will get better (and there will be less of them).

Comment: The main query does not always return results in the same order. Test again with `ORDER BY id`.

Comment: Things happen to be more complicated than just adding ORDER BY. All 6 rows have the same c1 column values. If I used "ORDER BY c1 DESC", then I got the same undesired result. However those 6 rows have different values on column c2. When I used "ORDER BY c2 DESC", I can loop through all 6 rows of data correctly. Now comes another question - why mysql does not ORDER and return SELECT **** ORDER by yy DESC LIMIT 2, 2  correctly when all rows have identical yy column value.

Comment: If mysql ORDER BY & LIMIT together cannot return complete query info when all rows have same column values, what shall we do then to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the order by clause to your sql query, or else there is no point in having a limit. 
 Use the following 
 `SELECT id FROM table WHERE c1=2 ORDER BY id LIMIT 2,2`
 This should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: For the record, there is still a point in having a limit without an order, there's just not a point in having an offset. limits have plenty of uses outside the OPs.

Answer (score 0):

Always use `ORDER BY` when you need the data to be sorting. Then you can filter the data by using `LIMIT` .

Try this :-

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE c1=2 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 2,2;
```

For `LIMIT` you can get any row position as per your need.Here I took 2,2 means starts from 2nd row position and total record will show 2.

Note :-

```
ORDER BY (DESC) - Descending Order
ORDER BY (ASC) - Ascending Oder
```

[Read more here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Hope it will help you.